AggregateResult does not support queryMore for only a single user
For one of our customers, we're having this really strange situation where a single user is running into an issue where they are getting this message. Aggregate query does not support queryMore(), use LIMIT to restrict the results to a single batch. Please contact your Administrator. I think we've isolated the issue to a section in the code the get's the COUNT and GROUP BY to aggregate the number of models that assets have.
We tried with a number of other users, some with less permissions then this tested user, as well as with our admin account, who has access to everything.
The problem is that we can't reproduce this issue with any other users. We are also unable to reproduce this issue in any of our scratch org or sandbox environments, and I was wondering if the AggregateResult query reacts differently depending on different user settings? (I read that that error would arise when AggregateResult has more then 2000 values, but for some reason that's not occurring when I test it with the dev console, despite there being over 3k grouped values from the AggregateResult, aggregating around 30k records.

This error can occur for what I loosely call "data intensity", meaning that it is not strictly a function of the number of records, but rather, a function of the number of bytes returned
